# Downloading Google+ photos into iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, google

I have a bunch of photos uploaded to Google+ from an Android phone.  I'd like to import them into iPhoto on my Mac, which is where I store my photos.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is your question how to import photos from Google+ into iPhoto on a Mac?

Comment: That's correct.